# React key prop error even after adding it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, key

[Key prop error UL tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqJwG.png)

**Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the top-level render call using .**

I have added key prop for every ul tags inside my code, but the error is still unresolved. I tried adding main key prop inside the return div tag also.

in React. The error message always tells you the offending component, but not the specific HTML tag / virtual DOM element that is offending. Working in a large code base with sometimes big components, this makes finding the source of the error very difficult.

```
var View = deviceTypes.map((deviceType,idx) => {
            
        );
    }
```

Comment: Could you please log your `devices` object?

Answer (score 0):

This div is the only element that needs a key:

```
var deviceView = deviceTypeData.map((deviceData) => {
  //...
  return (
     <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       //...
     </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you , I have tried that , but still the error says to check top level <ul> tag

Answer (score 0):

you need to put unique `key` inside the `div` that wraps the `ul`

```
                var imageView   = (<div key={idx} className={ImageBackGround}>
                    {image}

                    {typeof operationView!='undefined' &&  <div className= {typeof operationView=='undefined'?'':'mt-overlay'}>
                        <ul key={idx} className="mt-info">
                            {operationView}
                        </ul>
                    </div>}

                </div>);
```